# Libreoffice Calc / Excel - Multiple IF statments

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm at a loss here, I'm just wanting to match the contents of a cell to a partial value and if true, set the value in a new cell.

Colum E2 contents (2 rows):

```
MCDONALD'S #49019 QF5
THRIFTY FOODS #5649 NEW YORK
```

In cell E3 for example I have this:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("*MCDONALD'S*", E2)), "no match", "fast food"),
IF(ISERR(SEARCH("*THRIFTY FOODS*", E2)), "no match", "grocery")
```

It results in an error.

Now if I just have the first condition:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("*MCDONALD'S*", E2)), "no match", "fast food")
```

Then is works just fine, so how do I get this to work with multiple conditions?

Also trying this, with no success. It successfully matches the first criteria, but when the second criteria matches I just get the "Error" value...

```
=IFERROR( IF(SEARCH("MCDONALD'S", E3),"Fast Food", IF(SEARCH("THRIFTY", E3),"Grocery", "No Match" ) ) ,"Error")
```

Comment: Also trying this, with no success. It successfully matches the first criteria, but when the second criteria matches I just get the "Error" value.. =IFERROR( IF(SEARCH("*MCDONALD'S*", E3),"Fast Food",  IF(SEARCH("*THRIFTY*", E3),"Grocery", "No Match"    ) ) ,"Error")

Comment: Still, I don't understand what the result should be for your example: the cell has both the values being checked (""MCDONALD'S" and "THRIFTY FOODS") - apparently the formula should have returned **fast food;grocery**, right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the expected result.